# PHPMailer is not sending mail with forgot username page

Tags: php, email

Constructing Forgot UserName Page:

Withing php file is getting hosted under localhost xampp.
Using Gmail email address to send mail to another gmail address with username

No error, just mail is not sent.

I added the following files from Github inside the includes directory.

1. PHPMailerAutoload.php,
2. class.phpmailer.php,
3. class.smtp.php,
4. class.phpmaileroauth.php,
5. class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php,
6. class.pop3.php

Then inside includes directory created "forgot_username_inc.php" UPDATED
Here is the php code for it

```
<?php
 include_once 'db_connect.php';
 include_once 'psl-config.php';
 require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
 require_once 'class.smtp.php';
 require_once 'class.phpmaileroauth.php';
 require_once 'class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php';
 require_once 'class.pop3.php';
 $error_msg_username = "";

  if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
// Sanitize and validate the data passed in
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Not a valid email
    $error_msg_username .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered 
    is not valid</p>';
}

$prep_stmt = "SELECT username FROM client WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

  // check existing email  
  if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if (!($stmt->num_rows == 1)) {
        // If no user with such email
        $error_msg_username .= '<p class="error">No User Registered with that Email</p>';
                    $stmt->close();
    }      

} 

else {
    $error_msg_username .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
            $stmt->close();
}

  if (empty($error_msg_username)) {

  if($stmt_username = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM *** WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
   $stmt_username->bind_param('s', $email);
   $stmt_username->execute();
   $stmt_username->store_result();
   $stmt_username->bind_result($username);

   // user found
    if ($stmt_username->num_rows == 1) {
    // sending mail
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP 
authentication
   $mail->Port     = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL 
    server
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 
    'ssl' also accepted
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mail->From = 'example@gmail.com';
  $mail->FromName = 'Admin';
  $mail->addAddress($email);        // Name is optional
  $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 
 characters
   $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to 
  HTML

 $mail->Subject = 'User Name Forgot';
 $mail->Body    = 'Here is your UserName'.$username;
 $mail->AltBody = 'Here is your UserName'.$username;

  if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
 }
 //---End of Mail       
    } // end of userfound
   } // end of prepare statement

    if (! $stmt_username->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Username Search: FAILED');
            exit();
        }
        $stmt_username->close();
    header('Location: ./forgot_username_success.php');
    exit();
}

    }
    ?>
```

Error it shows:

> Please log in via your web browser Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

**What I did:** Disable 2-way authentication.Allow less secure apps access.
clear browser cache. I also "unlock CAPTCHA" 
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
Still failed.

**UPDATE:**
I used GMX instead of gmail & now it sending mails successfully.

Comment: Does it say `Message has been sent` ?

Comment: Is your gmail account configured to allow less secure apps? Google silently blocks sending mails if that setting is set to off.

Comment: no it just redirect to forgot_username_success page where I added custom message "your mail sent"

Comment: @FMashiro at example@gmail.com email settings do I need to make any changes, example@gmail.com mail has  POP is enabled for all mail also the  IMAP is enabled

Comment: add `die();` just right behind the closing bracket of your `if(!$mail->send()){}else{}` that way you'll see if you actually get an error.

Comment: @FMashiro Adding die*(); shows blank page after hitting submit button

Comment: @mimi did you add it where you have the comment saying 'end of mail' ?  \

Comment: @FMashiro Now added correctly it says "Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty"

Comment: @mimi there you go, you don't have a message in your email, if you put a correct string in there, it will work again.

Comment: @FMashiro Hi I added all required body data & dubug features updated post. Now it shows wrong username password, but my username & password is correct.

Comment: I have two step verification enabled may be thats why.

Comment: @mimi this new error is pretty self-explanatory, follow the steps provided by google: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636336263913928456-3397918875&rd=2#cantsignin

Comment: @mimi did you log in through your webbrowser?